# Can I do prayer at this time?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, madhhab

So I am a Muslim, I use the Hanafi fiqh (so does the rest of my family), and I use ‘Islamic University of Sciences, Karachi’ as my calculation method (because it matches with Abu Hanifa’s opinion), but my parents actually use ISNA. They say my prayer times are wrong (they just don’t get the calculation methods, that’s all), so I am thinking of using ISNA like them. Is it appropriate for me to use ISNA if I use Hanafi sources? Also, what if they ask me to go to the masjid with them, on Shafi’i Asr, as they don’t get the opinions of the Imams. Should I go with them? In short:

Questions:

1. Can I switch my calculation method from IUSK to ISNA so a unity in prayer time happens with my family?
2. Can I go with them to the Shafi’i, Maliki, Hanbali Asr if they force me to?

Jazakallahu Khairan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the differences in prayer timings between abu Hanifa and any other school of fiqh are applied -as an option- in each calculation method, the main distinction is the 'Asr prayer time and maybe the Fajr time (as it is somewhat discussed).

The most correct calculation method for your location depends on your actual location. ISNA is best for northern America, Karachi best for Pakistan and the closest countries. So either or both of you are using a wrong calculation method for example if you live in Europe, both of you would be wrong.

Now to your questions:

- You and your family should chose the most correct and adequate calculation method for your location.
- As said above in (at least 3 or) 4 out of 5 prayer timings the 4 major sunni school are in consensus about the timing so you could easily pray almost all prayers according the view of the scholars of the maliki, shafi'i and hanbali schools of fiqh, but in case of doubt you could delay your 'Asr prayer to perform it at the time of 'Asr according to the hanafi school of fiqh.

Also read:
[Figuring out right calculation method of prayer time](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/figuring-out-right-calculation-method-of-prayer-time/)
[Should I follow the prayer times of an app or from the local masjid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40176/should-i-follow-the-prayer-times-of-an-app-or-from-the-local-masjid)?
[Prayer times calculation organisations differences?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/prayer-times-calculation-organisations-differences)
[Time of Asr Salah according to Safi'i and Hanafi can I follow both?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/time-of-asr-salah-according-to-safii-and-hanafi-can-i-follow-both)

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what the connection is between Karachi's Islamic University of Sciences calculation method and Abu Hanifa's opinion. None of the jurisprudence schools differ on the calculation methodology to the best of my knowledge. The calculations are a function of:

- [Declination of the Sun as seen from Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun#Declination_of_the_Sun_as_seen_from_Earth)
- [Equation of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time)
- [Geographic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) (viz. the latitude and the longitude of one's location).

The calculations start by determining the *dhuhr* prayer time as a function of the equation of time and the geographic coordinates. The *fajr* and *'ishā'* prayer times are offset from the time of the *dhuhr* prayer (calculation-wise) by using a specific angle at which the sun is below the horizon. These angles for *fajr* and *'ishā'* prayers are the ones that differ by the calculation method. These are not based on a specific madhhab; rather, on a survey authority (Egypt, Iran, North America, Pakistan, and Saudi Arabia, in addition to the Muslim World League authority).

The differences among the madhhabs are for two prayers: *'asr* and *'ishā'*. The majority (not all) of the followers of the Hanafi school differ from the followers of the Maliki, the Shafi'i, and the Hanbali schools in regards to the start time of these prayers. The majority of Hanafis state that the *'asr* prayer time begins when the height of one's shadow is twice one's height, and the *'ishā'* prayer time begins after the setting of the white twilight (which is a few minutes after the setting of the red twilight).

Answer (score 0):

In principle, one may choose to follow any Madhhab and/or calculation method. Having said that, one should learn a madhhab and then focus on acting upon it. You shouldn't switch Madhhabs and calculation methods for your own convenience.

At the end of the day, these are just means of developing one's relationship with Allah. They matter because they affect the way you worship. Don't change them and don't let anyone force you from what you believe.

And Allah knows best.